# How to concat cell data for filtered rows in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I need to concat a list of related SKUs by their color. Column A is the SKU, B is the product name, and C is the color. For example: 10 colors of shirts in small, 10 colors in medium, and 10 in large. The data is organized by size, such as black small, red small, yellow small, etc. and I need to relate the colors so black small will cross associate with black medium and black large.

I would normally do this by adapting the formula on [this page](https://www.exceltactics.com/combine-data-multiple-rows-one-cell/2/) and running the macro below, so that every change in column B concats all the SKUs from column A. The problem is this doesn't work when filtering column C to only choose the color black, or white, or blue, etc. How do I achieve the result?

I would normally do this by following these steps.

1. in column D enter this formula: `=IF(A2<>A1,B2,C1 & "," & B2)`
2. in column E enter this formula: `=IF(AW2<>AW3,AY2)`
3. fill columns D and E down. Copy and past values of D, and clear all “FALSE” cells
4. run the following macro:

```
    Sub FillDown()

      Dim r As Range

      For Each r In Range("D:D").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Areas
            r.Value = r.Offset(r.Rows.Count).Resize(1).Value
      Next r

    End Sub
```

But this only works when not filtering column C.

**EDIT**:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/kSPyw.jpg

Above is a sample image showing some of the data I'm working with, and the desired result. The end result would be where a new column would have all the SKUs delimited by comma, if they have the same name. So for "tapered bar pull" it would be M2100,M2101,M2102,M2103,M1171,M1174 on rows 14, 17, 20, 23, 27, and 30.

I'm open to VBA, and changed the tags to include that in the post. Apparently I can't post images because I don't have the rep.

Comment: Can you show sample data instead of describing it? With desired output. Also, you haven't tagged VBA, but you describe the use of macros, are you open to both vba and formula answers?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I hope my edits make it clearer.

Comment: @gangula made a bad edit suggestion which I accepted before realizing it. Took a good 30 minutes to fix his mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So here is a solution on formulas:

[image]

Formula in `D2`:

```
=IF(C2=$D$1,TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,IF(($B$2:$B$12=B2)*($C$2:$C$12=$D$1),$A$2:$A$12,"")),"")
```

Entered through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

Drag down.

[image]

As you can see it will still work after a filter is applied.

[image]

This is based on an array formula that will only calculate when it's column C value equals `D1`. Because it's arrays its good to have this simple check before a heavy calculation.

Note it's a function only available from Excel 2016 under certain subscription I believe. However, you can go the VBA route, but then you should look into `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)`.

Comment: This worked once I changed the 12s in the formula to match the actual number of rows in the spreadsheet. Although, for some reason, the first column has an excessive number of commas in some cells. Thank you.